# Create an alias in Git to combine three separate commands

Tags: git

I'm rather new to using Git and Github but what I'd essentially like to do is stage the changes I've made to the files in my Git project, commit them and then push them up to Github using a defined remote.

So instead of these three commands submitted sequentially:

- `git add index.js`
- `git commit -m "new change"`
- `git push -u origin master`

I would like to just use:

- `git adpush "new change"`

I tried making said Alias with this code:

- `git config --global alias.adpush '!git add -A && git push -u origin master && git commit -m '`

But it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In your alias, you're pushing before you're committing?

Comment: It looks like your command order is mixed up. Try executing the commit before the push. In order to "push" your commits, the commits must be created first. Also, can you clarify what you mean when you say that it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What OS are you on? I'd suggest just making a bash function or the equivalent for the OS you're using.